# Jenkins wait for artifact download to finish

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am downloading multiple artifacts with Artifactory

```
rtDownload (
serverId: 'Artifactory-1',
spec: '''{
      "files": [
        {
          "pattern": "bazinga-repo/froggy-files/",
          "target": "bazinga/"
        }
      ]
}''',

// Optional - Associate the downloaded files with the following custom build name and build number,
// as build dependencies.
// If not set, the files will be associated with the default build name and build number (i.e the
// the Jenkins job name and number).
buildName: 'holyFrog',
buildNumber: '42'
)
```

Which works but this works asynchronously, and I have to use the results as soon as it finished. How do I await for each rtDownload in pipeline syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be done in declarative syntax, but you can use [scripted pipeline syntax](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/exclude-patterns-download-example/Jenkinsfile), which is synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me with downloading two artifacts:

```
def target = params.BuildInfo.trim()

def downloadSpec = """{
  "files": [{
    "pattern": "${artifactory}.zip",
    "target": "./${target}.zip"
  }]
}"""

def buildInfo = server.download spec: downloadSpec
def files = findFiles(glob: "**/${target}.zip") // Define `files` here

if (files) { // And verify `it` here, so it'll wait 
...
}
```

Comment: I ended up using something similar and I know it worked, since pipeline syntax is synchronous. I guess I can accept this even tho I cannot really test it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I ended up implementing Khoa's idea this way

```
  try {
    // attempt to retreive the results from artifactory
    rtDownload (
      serverId: 'my_arti_server',
      spec: """{
        "files": [
          {
            "pattern": "somepath/run_*.zip",
            "target": "run/"
          }
        ]
      }""",
      failNoOp: false, // no failure if no file was found
    )

    // rtDownload is async, we have to wait for dl completion
    def count = 5
    while(count > 0) {
      sh script:"""#!/bin/bash +e
        chmod 777 run/run_*.zip
      """  
      def files = findFiles glob: "run/run_*.zip"
      if (files.length > 0 ){
        break
      }
      sleep(5)
      count--
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    echo 'Exception occurred: ' + e.toString() 
  }

  def files = findFiles glob: "run/run_*.zip"
  if (files.length == 0 ){
    error("files couldn't be found")
  }
```

This is not perfect but it waits for some files to be present. If you have only  one file it should work but if you have several files, it may continue as soon as one file is downloaded. I haven't checked but with this I assume that:

- a file can be found once the download is completed (no file size changing regularly)
- all files are downloaded "at the same time"